# Tripod head for video panning and long exposure with EOS7D with Canon 70-200 f2.8 lens?

Tags: tripod, canon-7d, tripod-heads

I have a Canon EOS 7D (no grip) with 24-70 f2.8 and 70-200 f2.8 lens, and I
shoot long exposure night shots of stars and also panning videos of panorama landscapes.

From experience, which tripod head and tripod do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You need two different heads for these two things.

For the former, I don't have any direct experience, but you really need a tracking head that can counter the Earth's rotation.  Such setups tend to be relatively pricey and rather unique to the field of astrophotography.

For the later, I'm a huge fan of my Bogen Manfrotto 3046 base with 501HD head, which is my general purpose tripod since I do a fair amount of video in addition to photography.  You may want to go for a lighter set of legs for increased mobility, but you will certainly want a fluid head for anything that requires smooth motion.